# Maytag washer Duet direct drive. stuck , door won't open

Tags: washing-machine

I have model # WFW72HEDW0 Whirlpool Duet Washer   cannot open door,  stopped in cycle.   cannot turnoff power from panel.  last showed an E1 error code.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Have you tried pulling and replacing the power code? Some Googling suggested that the drain filter or pump may be indicated by the E01 error code.